# how to change the default icon while creating a template using multiple projects using vsix

Tags: c#, vsix

I want to create a template by multiple projects. for this  a exported a template for each project and created one root.vstemplate. while exporting each project I have changed the icon and also changed in meta data file that is in vsix projects manifest file. but default icon is displaying in project template.

this is the root.vstemplate

```
     <VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
<TemplateData>
    <Name>IT DevKit Phone</Name>
    <TemplateGroupID>WinRT-Managed</TemplateGroupID>
    <Description>An example of an image template</Description>
<Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
     <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<TargetPlatformName>Windows</TargetPlatformName>
    <RequiredPlatformVersion>8</RequiredPlatformVersion>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>           
    <SolutionFolder Name="WindowsPhone8">
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="PhoneApp1">
              PhoneApp1\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="PhoneApp2">
               PhoneApp2\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </SolutionFolder>
        </ProjectCollection>
</TemplateContent>
```

Comment: Have you set an icon in the root.vstemplate?

Comment: yes I have set as below    <VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>IT DevKit Phone</Name>
        <TemplateGroupID>WinRT-Managed</TemplateGroupID>
        <Description>An example of an image template</Description>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
         <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
 <TargetPlatformName>Windows</TargetPlatformName>
        <RequiredPlatformVersion>8</RequiredPlatformVersion>
    </TemplateData>

Comment: If you want to show us code, please *edit* your question and add it (also, highlight it and hit the `{}` button). Code in comments is almost always unreadable, especially if it contains XML.